# How can i insert a BLOB in mysql trough query

Tags: mysql, hex, blob

Does anyone know how i can enter an integer or hexadecimal value into a BLOB in mysql?

The endresult that i need is that the binary data of my blob contains:

```
Offset       1    2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   A   B  C  D  E  F
___________________________________________________________
0x00000000   15  AA   02  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00 00 00 00 00
```

The current blob holds the value : 174613

So how would i write an insert/update query to put that value into this BLOBb?

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution:

```
insert into tablename(columnname) values(x'15AA02000000000000000000000000')
```

`columnname` has to be of type `BLOB`.